# How to integrate and use ReportNG

Tags: automated-tests

Added the following .jar files to TestNG suite

```
reportng-1.1.4.jar
velocity-dep-1.4.jar
guice-3.0.jar
```

turned off the default listeners of the same. But reportNG is not working. The results are shown by TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

Add velocity-1.4.jar too.It is different from velocity-dep-1.4.jar.

Also add the listener for HTMLReporter in your xml file.

> `<`listeners>
>       `<`listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" /> 
>   `<`/listeners>

In case you wanted to know all the jars needed you can use maven dependency in a dummy project . This will download the jars on maven build and you can copy the jars from there for your project.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
```